# VIES VAT getting information on company

Tags: web-services

i'm having some difficulties with the use of VIES VAT. I'm using the webservice in http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/vatResponse.html and i'd like to know if it is possible to get the company address divided into Street, Zip Code and so on.

Comment: The provided link is a HTML page not the WSDL, which would help to answer your question. If the WSDL is http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl which method would you be calling. Some responses contain street, zip code, city, etc info. Which method is it you want to access?

Comment: I know that i'm just pointing to the working site. I would be using checkVat that returns the Address, but the problem is that it returns the whole address, meaning Street, Zip Code and City. Can you help me to separate it individually?

Comment: OK. It's the CheckVat method and indeed the returned address is a string. How does that string look like (any unique delimiters between street, zip code, city, etc). If yes, in Java it's a simple java.lang.String.split operation which returns an array with the splited items.

Comment: hmmm.... there are no delimiters, and that's the reason form e to be asking here, they are individual strings that are returned, by the webservice, as one string concatenated.
Example: 
Zip Code:1111-A
Street:Nowhere Lane Outta Sight 90378
State:State
and i get the resulting string
1111-ANowhere Lane Outta Sight90378State

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your information, no, since there are no unique delimiters or a unique pattern to identify the content of the address string.